# How to update XML Schema Collection using SQL Server Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication, xml-schema-collection

I am testing using SQL Server 2014 to replicate (using Merge Replication) a database between two servers. I have already setup replication successfuly and I am now testing how to apply changes to the database.

This database uses a few XML Schema Collections that may need to be updated in the future as new features are added to the system. After searching the web, I came to the conclusion that the only way I could replicate the changes to XML Schema Collections was by reinitializing the subscriber.

When I set a subscriber to be reinitialized a new snapshot is created with the updated XML Schema Collections. However, when the merge agent always fails to apply this change has it always tries to read the file containing the changes to the schema from the original snapshot that has already been deleted. The error messages shown are:

```
The schema script 'XXXXXXSchema_92.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
The process could not read file '\\SERVER\Path\unc\Publication\20140613183751\XXXXXXSchema_92.sch' due to OS error 3. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20216)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20216
```

In this case, the agent s trying to read from the original snapshot, 20140613183751, but the available snapshot is 20140613185435.

Is it possible to replicate schemas by reinitializing the subcripitons? Am I doing anything wrong?